# How to add and move images with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a text editor like “word” in which you can write text and also add some images and move them on the screen (drag them with the mouse and change their place on the screen).

I made the text editor using “Text” object in Tkinter, but in order to add images and move them with the mouse, “Canvas” object is required.
There is a way to merge those objects? Or there is an option to add and move images with “Text” object? (I succeeded to add an image to it but not to move it”)

Comment: You cannot change from one problem to another in the same post, so if you have another problem then create another post. Please read [ask] and pass the [tour]